# Angular Universal not working in pages with ngrx effects POST requests

Tags: angular5, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to convert my SPA built in Angular 5.2.11 and ngrx 5.2.0 to an Universal app.

My main strategy to make my POST/GET requests easily reusable through my components is to create a reducer for each one of these requests, subscribes to them and dispatch an action from a component when I need to retrieve some API data and manage UI state with variables configs from my store.

All pages without store subscriptions and dispatches are working perfectly, but the ones that have them are not. This is the error that my node server prints in the console when I try to hit those pages:

```
ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
    at resolvePromise (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Projects\Services\O
ngoing Projects\experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js
:814:31)
    at resolvePromise (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Projects\Services\O
ngoing Projects\experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js
:771:17)
    at C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Projects\Services\Ongoing Projects\
experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:873:17
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Projects\S
ervices\Ongoing Projects\experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zon
e-node.js:421:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Projects\Servi
ces\Ongoing Projects\experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\@angular\core\bundle
s\core.umd.js:4789:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Projects\S
ervices\Ongoing Projects\experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zon
e-node.js:420:36)
    at Zone.runTask (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Projects\Services\Ong
oing Projects\experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:1
88:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Projects\Servi
ces\Ongoing Projects\experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-no
de.js:595:35)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Projects\Servi
ces\Ongoing Projects\experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-no
de.js:500:21)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Projects\Services\
Ongoing Projects\experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.j
s:485:48)
    at data.args.(anonymous function) (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\GitHub\Pro
jects\Services\Ongoing Projects\experiences-2018-test\app\node_modules\zone.js\d
ist\zone-node.js:1317:25)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
  rejection: [Error],
  promise: ZoneAwarePromise { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: [Er
ror] },
  zone:
   Zone {
     _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
     _parent:
      Zone {
        _properties: {},
        _parent: null,
        _name: '<root>',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     _name: 'angular',
     _zoneDelegate:
      ZoneDelegate {
        _taskCounts: [Object],
        zone: [Circular],
        _parentDelegate: [Object],
        _forkZS: null,
        _forkDlgt: null,
        _forkCurrZone: [Object],
        _interceptZS: null,
        _interceptDlgt: null,
        _interceptCurrZone: [Object],
        _invokeZS: [Object],
        _invokeDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeCurrZone: [Circular],
        _handleErrorZS: [Object],
        _handleErrorDlgt: [Object],
        _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular],
        _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
        _invokeTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
        _cancelTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _hasTaskZS: [Object],
        _hasTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular],
        _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular] } },
  task:
   ZoneTask {
     _zone:
      Zone {
        _properties: [Object],
        _parent: [Object],
        _name: 'angular',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     runCount: 0,
     _zoneDelegates: null,
     _state: 'notScheduled',
     type: 'microTask',
     source: 'Promise.then',
     data: ZoneAwarePromise { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: [Er
ror] },
     scheduleFn: undefined,
     cancelFn: null,
     callback: [Function],
     invoke: [Function] } }
```

I'm pretty sure that this is because of ngrx library or angular's HttpClientModule, but I couldn't trace the origin of this error, because this is related to zone-node.js library.

Does someone know why this is happening and how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code instead of only the stack trace. You have an uncaught error somewhere..

Comment: Well, I just can't figure out which part of my code to show... I couldn't trace where it might be happening =/. I was hoping someone with a similar problem would share the solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Include your effects and service calls.